# Vue axios not sending headers to server (django simplejwt)

Tags: django, vue.js, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

It works well in postman. But I have this error when I do a axios request from Vue.

:

```
'Authentication credentials were not provided.'
```

If I write some custom header in postman, I can see it in request.headers.
But there is no header infomation in it if I construct headers in axios.

component.vue

```
test_auth: function(){

  var accessToken = this.$store.state.accessToken;
  console.log(accessToken);
  axios.get('http://django:8000/api/uvs/',{headers:{
    'Authorization':`Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    

  }} )
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    });

},
```

and my server settings

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://django:8080",
    "http://django",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://vue:8080",
    "http://vue",
]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True



REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',

    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
 

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
 
}
```

and views.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')



class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem comes from `axios.get`
I don't know why, but it works when I use `axios.create()` and use `intercepter` to add headers with Authorization Token for every request.
Then I call `axios_instance.get` and then I can send my Token via headers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
 

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
 
}
```

then call the function like this

```
test_auth: function(){

  var accessToken = this.$store.state.accessToken;
  console.log(accessToken);
  axios.get('http://django:8000/api/uvs/',{headers:{
    'Authorization':`Token ${accessToken}`,
    

  }} )
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    });

},
```